# What would be the most basic Mac Mini to test LibGDX apps on for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macos, testing, libgdx

I am developing apps for Android using LibGDX, and I would like to publish them for iPhone as well. I do not own a Mac and I heard that a Mac Mini would be a cheap solution to develop for iPhone.

What are the minimum requirements for a Mac Mini to test apps on? I would be primarily developing on Windows, so my idea would be that it's okay if the Mac is not the fastest one. I just need it primarily for testing.

I would like to know the minimum CPU, memory, O/S, and software that is necessary for testing.

Comment: The cheapest one they make. Then upgrade RAM to 8GB or more (don't buy overpriced RAM from Apple store). MacOS updates are free, and there is no software to buy.

Comment: Thank you. I've read that Xcode requires at least Mac OS X 10.10.4+ to run Xcode 7. I'm not sure if the cheapest one would run that OS. What do you think?

Comment: Yes. I bought the cheapest Mac Mini four years ago and it runs it fine. There have been two updates to the Mac Mini line since then. The biggest bottleneck was the 4GB of RAM it came with, so you definitely need at least 8GB.
You can get compatible RAM from Crucial or Newegg.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do you work with LibGDX?

Comment: Yes. I haven't released a Libgdx app on iOS yet, but I've been running test builds.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Is it difficult to switch from Android to IOS using LibGDX? I use a few Android specific techniques, but my app is mostly cross-platform built. You may post your previous comments as answer and I'll accept it for you.

Comment: I guess it's totally dependent on what Android features you're using. In my game, I've planned for iOS from the beginning. In two evenings, I got it to selectively use GameCenter on iOS while using Google Play Game Services on Android. In one evening I got it to tweet screenshots using built-in sharing on iOS and Twitter Fabric on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a second hand Mac Mini with an SSD and 8GB RAM which can run the latest version of Mac OSX: El Capitan. It works perfectly, although it is not the fastest, it is not terribly slow either.

This is important: The Mac Mini needs to be able to run the latest version of Mac OSX and XCode.

For more information, see:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-ios